# How to access image in Android from Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a Flutter project that works well on both the iOS and Android platform.

In the Flutter project, there is an image located in ***android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/temp.jpg***,

and I want to load that image and use it in the Flutter widget.

I have tried to find answer in the document [Adding assets and images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) and [Flutter for Android developers](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs) but no luck.

How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: [Flutter for Android](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#where-do-i-store-my-resolution-dependent-image-files) mentioned that you can access images directly in an image widget. For example, `Image.asset("images/my_image.png");`. Have you tried this?

Comment: @Uni I know the way you mentioned, and it do works, but I was wondering how to access images that are **located in path that I mentioned in the question**. Or putting images in that location is a bad idea?

Comment: @jabamataro Yes, it works when I access the images located under the images folder, but not works for the path that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Shan have you tried changing the path to `Image.asset("android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/temp.jpg");`? Note that you need to define it first in pubspec.yaml

Comment: @jabamataro It works!! You save my day, thanks! I am new to Flutter so did not realized it can work like that. I will update the answer based on your comments later. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @jabamataro How to do it for iOS?

Comment: @MuhammadQasim You can follow the instructions in [loading-flutter-assets-in-ios](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-flutter-assets-in-ios).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like @[jabamataro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11269204/jabamataro) mentioned in the comments, define the path `- android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/` in the `assets:` section of the `pubspec.yaml` file like below:

```
assets:
    - android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/
```

then the image could be used like:

```
AssetImage('android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/temp.jpg');
```

Hope this answer can help those new to Flutter development.

Comment: how can I do the opposite way, from Flutter directory to Android or xml's src tag ?

Comment: can't find example of using image reference in xml from android in flutter project, do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

Load images folder in **pubspec.yaml** like

```js
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

and then use it in image widget like

```js
child: Image.asset('assets/images/splash_logo.png',
        height: 150,
        width: 150,
      fit: BoxFit.cover),
```